# "My unqualified host name (foo.bar) unknown" Problem

Tags: sendmail, hostname, hosts, email-server

When trying to start `sendmail` or send a mail using a [wordpress plugin](https://serverfault.com/questions/57863/slow-mail-send-using-wordpress-and-sendmail), this error shows up in the `maillog`:

```
"My unqualified host name (foo.bar) unknown; sleeping for retry"
```

After [Googling](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=My+unqualified+host+name+&btnG=Search&meta=) the best advice was, "add foo.bar to the /etc/hosts file", but it already is:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain
127.0.0.1     foo.bar
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Simply changed:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain
127.0.0.1     foo.bar
```

To this

```
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain foo.bar
```

`Sendmail` looks for a fully qualified domain (FQDN) name and will use the `localhost.localdomain` in the single line version.

Comment: fixed my problem. Just want to be clear, it is the hostname that should be put in this line. So first use hostname command find it, than add it to this line in \etc\hosts . Thanks, man.

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: or actually use a domain name that exists and is configured properly. At least if you want your mail to get _delivered_ you should.

Comment: just to clarify it a bit - the foo.bar should be your `hostname`, to get your hostname easily run `$ hostname` . Then add the shown hostname to that line as suggested in this solution

Answer (score 3):

Simply adding the domain to your hosts files as @rjstelling suggests will only allow your mail to be *sent*, but it is incredibly unlikely to land in someone's inbox.

In order to send an email that won't be flagged as spam, to say nothing of the receiving server just terminating the delivery attempt or dropping the message, you need to be using a *real, registered* domain name with working DNS and an MX record.

And that is to say nothing for [FCRDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS) or any one of the *dozens* of things that you need to do to run a server whose email might actually be accepted most of the time. [if the internet gods deign to smile upon you even briefly] The true answer is that you probably shouldn't be running your own mailserver because it's simply not worth the work required to keep it in good standing. Look into mail services like SendGrid, MailChimp, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer:

```
    127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain foo.bar
```

seems to work, but produces the errors in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
    sendmail[11655]: gethostbyaddr(192.168.1.123) failed: 1
```

But leaving just

```
    127.0.0.1   localhost
```

in `/etc/hosts`, and removing the second line allows `mail` to get sent, and does not result in any errors.

Update: when doing `sudo ...whatever..` there is a message `sudo: unable to resolve host foo.bar`, but looks like it does not affect anything..

BTW, to restart the hostname service without reboot:

```
    systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed
```

On Ubuntu 16.04, but should not be necessary for `mail` to work after editing `/etc/hosts`