# Possible need to change hosts file to configure mail

Tags: centos, email, sendmail, host

My original problem was that the PHP mail() function wouldn't work for programs on my server, which is running Centos 5.5.

I have configired the firewall through a program called *system-config-securitylevel-tui* and the SMTP port is now open.

*sendmail* is installed.

I've looked in my *maillog* and I've got the following message:

> myhost sendmail[932]: My unqualified host name (myhost) unknown; sleeping for retry

Looking at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/58363/my-unqualified-host-name-foo-bar-unknown-problem) stackoverflow article I might need to make a change to my /etc/hosts file, but I'm not sure if my situation is the same as the above guys and I certainly don't know what I'm doing.

My hosts file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain
78.227.199.181     myhost (fake ip address)
```

From what I've read, I need to have a fully qualified domain name for the sendmail program to use.

Now I've set up my httpd webserver with the ServerName set to my domain name. How do I do the same sort of thing for the hosts file (ie how do I add the full domain name? Should the file just be:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain
78.227.199.181     myhost www.fulldom.tld
```

I don't want to run a mailserver on my server. I have a mail account set up. I just want the PHP function to work. Am I going in the right direction here do you think?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added my full domain name to the second line as in the above example and I can now send mail.